# Capture onClick event in serverside php file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am very new to Ajax. My application uses ajax (and a server side php page called Req.php) to fetch records from a database, create table using those fetched records and display it. Now I want a column to be added having Delete option to it. May be something like this:

```
echo '<td><a href="javascript:void()" onclick = "deleteIt($rowID)">Delete</a></td>';
```

This `deleteIt()` method lies inside Req.php (server side) file like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function deleteIt(rowID)
{
//Some Code
}

</script>
```

Now considering the fact that it is a server side file, and delete event happens at client side, what should be the procedure to capture this delete event so that it takes `$rowID` from the table made by server side php file and deletes the correponding record.

Any help would be highly appreciated. And please let me know if there's insufficient information so that I can give more details.

Comment: you can use ajax/jquery post method for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    jQuery.ajax({
                url:'YOUR PHP url which contains DELETE code',
                type:'POST',
                data:'SEND YOUR DATA',
                success:function(results){
                    jQuery("#oresponsecontainer").html(results);

                }
            });
```

In your PHP

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

An Ajax request would be then be sent from your javascript with the id and action (deleting) of the column your accepping php file would then search for the row and delete it.
please specify what has been done in php for deleting.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another php script that handles POST request (or GET, i've used post ajax)

so function should execute something like this

```
$.post("/trackDeletion.php",{rowID:rowID},function(successResponse){
//client handler
})
```

and PHP will be

```
rowID = $POST['rowID']
//do you code on backend
```